# Jcombobox doesn't close when selecting an option..!

Tags: java

when I select an option in jcombobox, it doesn't get close and throws null pointer exception...
the code is given below....

```
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) 
{
    String[] selectedItem=null;
    int i=0;
    ArrayList<String> sub_list = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        connection();
        String s1="select subnm from subject where branch='"+combobranch.getSelectedItem()+"'";
        System.out.println(s1);
        rs = st.executeQuery(s1);

        rs.first();

        while(rs.next())
        {
            selectedItem[i] = rs.getString("subnm");
            System.out.println(selectedItem[i]);
            if(!sub_list.contains(selectedItem))
            {
                sub_list.add(selectedItem[i]);
            }
        }
DefaultComboBoxModel(sub_list.toArray()));
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(admin.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

and the exceptions message shown below...!

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at admin.itemStateChanged(admin.java:1201)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.fireItemStateChanged(JComboBox.java:1223)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.selectedItemChanged(JComboBox.java:1271)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.contentsChanged(JComboBox.java:1327)
    at javax.swing.AbstractListModel.fireContentsChanged(AbstractListModel.java:118)
    at javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel.setSelectedItem(DefaultComboBoxModel.java:93)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedItem(JComboBox.java:576)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedIndex(JComboBox.java:622)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboPopup$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicComboPopup.java:834)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:290)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6527)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboPopup$1.processMouseEvent(BasicComboPopup.java:498)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6292)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4883)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
    }
```

plz help me out!!!

Comment: where do you intialize your `String[] selectedItem` array

Comment: at 2nd line!!!
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) 
{
String[] selectedItem=null;

Comment: initialize array like `String[] selectedItem=new String[length] ` .if you don't know the length use array-list

Comment: @JaynaTanawala It's initialized to `null`, so you get a `NullPointerException` where you use `selectedItem[i] = rs.getString("subnm");`. `selectedItem[i]` throws it, because `selectedItem` is `null`.

Comment: ok,, bt how to use arraylist with it??

Comment: Make `String[] selectedItem=null;` as `String selectedItem=null;`, remove the references of `selectedItem[i]` with `selectedItem`.